# Convert hundredths to “minutes:seconds.hundredths” in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, time

In Javascript, I need help to convert an integer with hundredths to "minutes:seconds.hundredths".

So for example, I have this: '10420' and want to display it like this: 01:44.20.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function leading0(number){ return number < 10 ? "0" : "";}

mins = parseInt((hundredths / 100) / 60)
secs = parseInt((hundredths / 100) % 60)
huns = parseInt(hundredths % 100)
output = leading0(mins) + mins + ":" + leading0(secs) + secs + "." + leading0(huns) + huns;
```

jsFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/cNu2t/

Comment: +1 but change `1000` to `100` in all cases, as they are hundredths, not milliseconds.

Comment: This give wrong results for 10402, and not in the expected format

Comment: works! 2 problems tho, if the time is for example 2:09.45 it shows 2:9.45 instead, is it possible to add that zero somehow? and is it possible to show a zero in front of the time when it's below 10 minutes? Thanks

Comment: I've changed 1000 to 100, sorry for writing in a hurry.

Answer (score 0):

```
var hundredths = 10420;
var seconds = Math.floor(hundredths / 100);
var minutes = Math.floor(seconds / 60);
return minutes+":"+(seconds-minutes*60)+"."+("0"+(hundredths-seconds*100)).substr(-2);
```

or:

```
function leadingZero(n) { return ("00"+n).substr(-2); }
var hundredths = 10420;
var secs = ~~(hundreths/100);
var mins = ~~(secs/60);
return mins+":"+leadingZero(secs%60)+"."+leadingZero(hundredths%100);
```

Answer (score 0):

[Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) should be able to handle this based on it's pretty rich set of formatting, parsing, etc. that it offers. I don't know if you'll be doing enough additional date and/or time related stuff to make adding a 5K JavaScript library to the set of resources you download for a page, but it might be worth a look if you have other spots where you could put it to use.

I know it deals in milliseconds and you can just multiply your number by ten to get to milliseconds and then pass it through their formatting function to output what you're after I think.